# Google Scripts No longer Working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

We have been using scrips lately for our google sheets and are now seeing a error in our system about - it says "We're sorry, a server error occurred.  Please wait a bit and try again."  We have closed our tabs several times and have refreshed our google sheet but every time we run a script it fails and gives us that message.  This just started happening about 1 week ago.  Any advice?

Thanks,

mark

Comment: In the script editor, run the script to re-authenticate.

Comment: Please post a sample snippet to help us in providing a better answer. Issue may be with Authorization as suggested by Mark.

Comment: Here is a copy of some of our script script //////////////

function onlyToAddTheDriveScope(){
  DriveApp.getRootFolder()
};

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Send Email", functionName: "sendEmail"}];
  ss.addMenu("Scripts", menuEntries);
};

                                               
function sendEmail() {
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  //var email = Session.getUser().getEmail();

Comment: Why would you post your function in a comment on your question *rather than in your question*, where it can be properly formatted and easily referenced?